# Flask-WTF: How to allow zero upon DataRequired() validation

Tags: validation, flask, flask-wtforms

I have defined a form like this:

```
class RecordForm(Form):
    rating = IntegerField('Rating')
```

If no value is inserted I get a default message like this:

```
Not a valid integer value
```

I would like to have a custom message instead, so I came up with this:

```
class RecordForm(Form):
    rating = IntegerField('Rating',[validators.DataRequired("Helllo???")])
```

The custom message works now, but I get a side effect.  0 (zero) is no longer accepted as an integer value.  What are my options here please?

Comment: Why -1 without any comments? if the question can be improved, please let me know.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [`InputRequired`](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/1.0.4/validators.html#wtforms.validators.InputRequired) instead:

```
class RecordForm(Form):
    rating = IntegerField('Rating',[validators.InputRequired("You got to enter some rating!")])
```

From the docs:

> Note there is a distinction between this and DataRequired in that InputRequired looks that form-input data was provided, and **DataRequired looks at the post-coercion data**.

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

Comment: thanks! this gave me keyboard bruises on my forehead.